# How to merge 3 data frames without the same column names and with different row numbers

Tags: r, excel, join, merge

How do I merge these 3 data frames together in R, given that they do not have the same column names, no common key, and they have different number of rows?

The data consists of 40 years of Eurasian blue tits breeding data.

The 3 dataframes are: Demo.data which contains the identity of the breeding pairs that years at a given site, and the identity of their offspring, and how many offspring fledged that year.

morph.data contains, contains morphological measurements of the parent birds (mass, tarsus length…).

The Chick.data set contains morphological data on the chicks.

One of the problems is that in the demo.data frame, the band numbers are in a different format than in the morph.data frame. For example: In the demo.data frame the male and female band numbers are side by side (which allows me to see which two birds formed a pair that year).
In the morph.data frame the band numbers are arranged in a column.
In the chick.data frame, the bands are also arranged in a column.

Another issue is that I have repeated band numbers across years. So I can’t simply join the spread sheets by band number.

The Models that I am trying to build:

`Mean_Off_tarsus ~ #_offspring  + Prnt_mass + Mean_Prnt_tarsus + (1|maleID) + (1|femaleID) + (1|nest ID) + (1|year)`

`Mean_Off_mass ~ #_offspring + Prnt_mass + Mean_Prnt_tarsus+(1|maleID) + (1|femaleID) + (1|nest ID) + (1|year)`

demographic data.frame:

```
structure(list(population = c("pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir",
```

"pir", "pir", "pir", "pir"),
year = structure(c(17L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("1976", "1977", "1978", "1979",
"1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987",
"1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995",
"1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003",
"2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011",
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019",
"2020", "2021"), class = "factor"),
nest = c("107", "72", "105",
"80", "110", "77", "77", "2", "37", "47"),
#offspring = c(5L,6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
maleBand# = c("3475700", "2709315",
"2709871", "2546628", "2546650", "2864916", "3034870", "2709096",
"2310927", "2310911"),
femaleband# = c("2221152", "2546612", "2546616",
"2546643", "2546644", "2546644", "2546644", "2546651", "2563274",
"2563341"),chickband1 = c("3945742", "2709339", "2709892", "2546630",
"2546645", "2864917", "3034911", "2709097", "2563288", "2563348"
), chickband2 = c("3945743", "2709340", "2709893", "2546631", "2546646",
"2864918", "3034912", "2709098", "2563289", "2563349"),
chickband3 = c("3945744",
"2709341", "2709894", "2546632", "2546647", "2864919", "3034913",
"", "2563290", "2563350"),  row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = "data.frame")

Morpological data frame

`structure(list(population = c("pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir","pir", "pir", "pir", "pir"), year = c(1992L, 1993L, 1992L, 1993L,1992L, 1985L, 1985L, 1983L, 1985L, 1985L), nest = c("48", "41",  "78", "4", "107", "14", "112", "114", "108", "114"), date_mesure = c("1992-06-11","1993-06-12", "1992-06-11", "1993-06-10", "1992-06-05", "1985-03-25", "1985-01-17", "1983-06-08", "1985-01-17", "1985-01-10"), band# = c("2221144","2221144", "2221147", "2221147", "2221152", "2546646", "2546658", "2546660", "2563352", "2563384"), sex = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), tarsus = c(15.66, 15.82, 15.8, 15.9, 15.63, 13.6, 14.4, 16.2, 14.1, 15.05), mass = c(8.9, 8.6, 9.6, 9.1,  9.2, 9, 12, 9.2, 10.7, 11.1)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")`

For the chick data.frame.
`structure(list(population = c("pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir",  "pir", "pir", "pir", "pir"), year = c(1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L,  1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1990L, 1990L),  nest = c("59", "59","59", "59", "59", "59", "20", "30", "57", "57"),  date_mesure = c("1991-06-07", "1991-06-07", "1991-06-07", "1991-06-07", "1991-06-07", "1991-06-07", "1992-06-09", "1992-06-09", "1990-06-06", "1990-06-06"),  Band# = c("2221124","2221125", "2221126", "2221127", "2221128", "2221129", "3364375","3364376", "3475222", "3475223"),  tarsus = c(16.14, 16.81, 15.18,15.52, 16.23, 15.61, 15.53, 16.7, 15.9, 14.68), mass = c(9.9, 10.9, 9.4, 9.9, 10.1, 10.5, 10.4, 10.7, 10.1, 9.9)),row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Hello, could you please provide the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` for each of the dataframes after you read them into R? Screenshots are challenging to work with. Thanks.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck? [mre] "appreciate suggestions" is not an on-topic question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? Where are you 1st stuck doing some part? PS Your tables are not "minimal". Also after you format the text version reasonably any images will be redundant. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Hi @dcsuka I imputed the code as requested. It looks pretty ugly to me and I'm not sure how helpful it will be. Please let me know if you need clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: Can you instead just copy and paste the output of `dput` in? The commenting from `reprex` makes this still difficult to read in.